# float image over div

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm building a [website](http://www.japadventure.dreamhosters.com/) that uses [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/).

At the bottom of the Home page 'in beeld' I want the right large image to overlap the footer a little bit so that the image floats over the gray 'hills'. I have been trying to add a negative margin to the image but then it partly dissapears under the footer.

Someone has an idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like simple matter of `z-index`.. just give the image higher `z-index` value than the footer.

Comment: @Shadow: I tried, but it doesn't work

Comment: i didn't add the relative position value as Deniss Kozlovs suggested. That did the trick. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative margin to your "in beeld" .paragraph and

```
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to give some opacity also then it perfectly floats.

```
position: relative; 
z-index: 100;
opacity: 0.50;
```